# ERROR! : Elastic search issue UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService'

Tags: jhipster

I have created jhipster micoservices project with React as appears below with jhipster version 5.5.0.

```
? Which *type* of application would you like to create? Microservice gateway 
? What is the base name of your application? desyappsvc
? As you are running in a microservice architecture, on which port would like your server to run? It should be unique to avoid port conflicts. 8181
? What is your default Java package name? com.hlp.svc
? Which service discovery server do you want to use? No service discovery
? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT authentication (stateless, with a token)
? Which *type* of database would you like to use? SQL (H2, MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MSSQL)
? Which *production* database would you like to use? PostgreSQL
? Do you want to use the Spring cache abstraction? Yes, with the Hazelcast implementation (distributed cache, for multiple nodes)
? Do you want to use Hibernate 2nd level cache? Yes
? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Gradle
? Which other technologies would you like to use? Search engine using Elasticsearch
? Which *Framework* would you like to use for the client? React
? Would you like to enable *SASS* stylesheet preprocessor? Yes
? Would you like to enable internationalization support? No
? Besides JUnit and Jest, which testing frameworks would you like to use? Gatling, Cucumber, Protractor
```

Please see below for my yo-rc.json.

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.hlp.svc"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "5.4.2",
    "applicationType": "gateway",
    "baseName": "desyappsvc",
    "packageName": "com.hlp.svc",
    "packageFolder": "com/hlp/svc",
    "serverPort": "8181",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "hazelcast",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "ZjNjYzQ5OGE4YTcyODRkMTlmNzFhMWI3MGZjZDNjMWM4NjM0M2QxYWJiY2RiN2M1NWI3ZTJmNTUxNWY0MTc2MTgwMzQ3ZGU0Mzk5N2QxM2ZhYWFmNDFiNjFmY2JhNWQwMTg4NWU1NjJhOTk0MjgzYTY3MDkwZjAwOWMyZjQ5NTc=",
    "clientFramework": "react",
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling",
      "cucumber",
      "protractor"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": false
  }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.IndexNotFoundException: no such index
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver$WildcardExpressionResolver.infe(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:678)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver$WildcardExpressionResolver.innerResolve(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:632)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver$WildcardExpressionResolver.resolve(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:580)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver.concreteIndices(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:169)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver.concreteIndexNames(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:145)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver.concreteIndexNames(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:78)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.get.TransportGetIndexAction.checkBlock(TransportGetIndexAction.java:63)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.get.TransportGetIndexAction.checkBlock(TransportGetIndexAction.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction.doStart(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:134)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction.start(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:126)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.doExecute(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.doExecute(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:170)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:142)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:84)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:83)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:72)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:408)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:1256)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.getIndex(AbstractClient.java:1357)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.admin.indices.RestGetIndicesAction.lambda$prepareRequest$0(RestGetIndicesAction.java:97)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:262)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:200)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(Netty4HttpServerTransport.java:505)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(Netty4HttpRequestHandler.java:80)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.channelRead(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:68)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:628)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:563)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2018-11-08 15:48:23.193 DEBUG 535548 --- [  restartedMain] c.g.v.s.jest.mapper.DefaultErrorMapper   : Cannot execute jest action , response code : 404 , error : 404 Not Found , message : null
Exception in thread "elasticsearch[9rNAzB7][clusterService#updateTask][T#1]" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext.getThreadContextMap()Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/spi/ThreadContextMap;
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContextAccess.getThreadContextMap(ThreadContextAccess.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataInjectorFactory.createDefaultInjector(ContextDataInjectorFactory.java:83)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataInjectorFactory.createInjector(ContextDataInjectorFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.ContextMapLookup.<init>(ContextMapLookup.java:34)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:116)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:32)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:72)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.setLevel(Configurator.java:291)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.setLevel(Loggers.java:149)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.setLevel(Loggers.java:144)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.SearchSlowLog.setLevel(SearchSlowLog.java:111)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.SearchSlowLog.<init>(SearchSlowLog.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.IndexModule.<init>(IndexModule.java:127)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.createIndexService(IndicesService.java:440)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.createIndex(IndicesService.java:413)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$1.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:378)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateUpdateTask.execute(ClusterStateUpdateTask.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService.executeTasks(ClusterService.java:634)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService.calculateTaskOutputs(ClusterService.java:612)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService.runTasks(ClusterService.java:571)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService$ClusterServiceTaskBatcher.run(ClusterService.java:263)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher.runIfNotProcessed(TaskBatcher.java:150)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher$BatchedTask.run(TaskBatcher.java:188)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:576)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:247)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2018-11-08 15:48:28.222  WARN 535548 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\workspace\DESY\desy-core-svc\bin\main\gov\hhs\cms\desy\service\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to execute action
2018-11-08 15:48:28.232  INFO 535548 --- [  restartedMain] a.d.j.ElasticsearchJestAutoConfiguration : Closing Elasticsearch client
2018-11-08 15:48:28.233  INFO 535548 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.h.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory        : Shutting down HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
2018-11-08 15:48:28.233  WARN 535548 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.h.i.IHazelcastInstanceFactory        : hibernate.cache.hazelcast.shutdown_on_session_factory_close property is set to 'false'. Leaving current HazelcastInstance active! (Warning: Do not disable Hazelcast hazelcast.shutdownhook.enabled property!)
2018-11-08 15:48:28.233  INFO 535548 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] [127.0.0.1]:5701 is SHUTTING_DOWN
2018-11-08 15:48:28.248  INFO 535548 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] Shutting down connection manager...
2018-11-08 15:48:28.248  INFO 535548 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] Shutting down node engine...
2018-11-08 15:48:28.248  INFO 535548 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.instance.NodeExtension     : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] Destroying node NodeExtension.
2018-11-08 15:48:28.248  INFO 535548 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] Hazelcast Shutdown is completed in 0 ms.
2018-11-08 15:48:28.248  INFO 535548 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] [127.0.0.1]:5701 is SHUTDOWN
2018-11-08 15:48:28.248  INFO 535548 --- [  restartedMain] g.h.cms.desy.config.CacheConfiguration   : Closing Cache Manager
2018-11-08 15:48:28.280 ERROR 535548 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\workspace\DESY\desy-core-svc\bin\main\gov\hhs\cms\desy\service\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to execute action
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
    at gov.hhs.cms.desy.DesyappsvcApp.main(DesyappsvcApp.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to execute action
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to execute action
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:182)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$getTargetRepositoryViaReflection$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:497)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:304)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:293)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:67)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to execute action
    at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.execute(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1223)
    at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.executeWithAcknowledge(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1228)
    at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:196)
    at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndexWithSettings(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1438)
    at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndexIfNotCreated(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1423)
    at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:177)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.createIndex(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:96)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.<init>(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository.<init>(NumberKeyedRepository.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

Please help me to resolve the Elasticsearch index not found issue

Comment: I have this error too. Any luck yet?

Comment: @Jagan You need to run an instance of elastic search. The in-memory option of ES was removed in the new ES versions and hence you need to run it with Docker.

Answer (score 1):

Jhipster Version: 5.7.2

For me the issue was resolved by :

1. Creating an external instance of Elastic Search(I used AWS ES with Elasticsearch version 6.4.2).
2. Deploying to AWS with the command: jhipster aws (The elastic beanstalk deployer)
3. Setting the environment variable in configuration (SPRING_DATA_JEST_URI=<
4. Restart your Elastic Beanstalk environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just few minutes ago. I am using **Jhipster 5.8.2**. I generated my application using ElasticSearch. I had created six (6) entities without problem and I just created two new one and the error described popup. I have **docker** install on my local laptop. I started it and I run the docker-compose command on the elasticsearch.yml file like this

> docker-compose -f src/main/docker/elasticsearch.yml up -d

To resole the issue I just restarted the docker app and re run the previous docker-compose command.

After that I just run **./mvnw** and **npm start** to see all functionning well again.

Answer (score 0):

`curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }' curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'` 
found this and worked for me:
https://selleo.com/til/posts/esrgfyxjee-how-to-fix-elasticsearch-forbidden12index-read-only
give it a try.

Comment: Could you please provide some explanation on your code?